# Visual Studio 2022: ASP.NET Webforms, autogenerated c# file in Temp folder prevents code from running

Tags: vb.net, webforms, .net-framework-version

I have a solution in Visual Studio containing a Website project (runs on Local IIS) and a class library containing three classes.

Recently I was having the following issue when debugging my code in VS:

> Source file: C:\Users\myUser\Code\Project\Classes\security.vb
> Module: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\TemporaryASP.NETFiles\vs\d6df7be\121dd593\assembly\dl3\d26ea02c\f4515c01_561eda01\MY_CLASS.dll
> Process: [36348] iisexpress.exe
>
> The source file is different from when the module was built. Would you like the debugger to use it anyway?

I then to delete the the `MY_CLASS.pdb` file in the bin > debug folder in my project to see if that would fix the issue.

Now the warning has gone away. However, when I debug and run the same section of code, a new `security.vb` class is generated (this time in C#) and it is stored in this location instead of the project folder:.

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\.vsdbgsrc\500a5fc407eac6bd6401fc88cd6411afb1673750889cb848c91\database.cs
```

How can I get the debugger to use the intended debug file?

Also, my project is targeted to be in .NET framework 4.8.0, and the temporary ASP.NET files are in v4.0.30319. Could this be causing any issue while debugging?

If anybody has any idea of what the issue could be here, I'd greatly appreciate it, this is my first time working with .NET.

Comment: The 4.8.0 vs 4.0.30319 discrepancy is **expected** and not a problem.  Later 4.x versions of the .Net framework still use the 4.0.x runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder for 4.xxxx etc. is simply where all .net 4.0+ to 4.8 goes. (there not a new folder for each version of .net).

Now, I assume (and this is VERY important) that you are using a asp.net web "application" and not a asp.net web site.

That means, when you build + deploy, then the source code (.vb) files are NOT included since you compile + build before a deploy.

As for the build of those classes?

Ok, so you have a folder called "Classes".

And inside you dump in (create) some .net class(s) to use.

Just make sure that with your "own" custom folder with code, you set the build options correctly (often we use app_code, but there are SIGNIFICANT reasons why I don't use that folder (more in a bit on this issue).

So, for a custom folder to work, such as MyApp_code, then make sure you right click, and set the build options. Since the folder is custom, then adding class(s) or code modules may well not always have the correct settings.

So, right click on the module/class in that folder, and check the build options. They should be set to this:

[image]

So, do not copy is correct, and the build action should = compile.

Next up:

> "The source file is different from when the module was built. Would you like the debugger to use it anyway?"

That's not good! Assuming a web site "application", then you can/should/often delete EVERYTHING inside of the bin folder. (WARNING!!!: THIS assumes an "application". So NEVER in ANY case EVER place. dll’s and other referenced assemblies inside of the bin folder. The bin folder is for project compiled output, and thus when done correctly, you are 100% free to delete everything inside of that bin folder.

And that means you should take a quick look/peek/examine of your project references and make 100%, 200% sure that no .dll's are referenced in the bin folder (since I just stated you should be free to "clean" project, or even delete everything inside of the bin folder).

Next up:

When you stated the code "looks" to appear as c#? yes, that means that Visual Studio will de-compile the .dll's in question.

Look close at the code, did VS de-compile the .dll for you?
(this defaults to c#).

So, you see this:
[image]

Note how it shows/says "decompiled" (the text is actually cut a bit! - it says decompiled).

However, if you CORRECTLY included the source code of that class, then decompiling SHOULD NOT occur.

It is RATHER possible you have multiple projects, or you included a reference to that other project/assembly.

There are several ways to solve this issue. For one, consider including the other project into your current project (in other words, do NOT reference the assembly, but in fact INCLUDE the project into the current project).

However, first, clear out your bin folder (delete everything). And then re-build. If you project builds, then you should be ok. And if you HAVE referenced other assembles (not included the project(s)), then change this setting in

tools->options->debugging->Enable Just My Code.

[image]

So, you can un-check the above. (I tend to keep it checked), but if you referenced several of your external class(s), then you have to un-check the above. Either way, LOOK CLOSE at the code tab, and look for the de-compiled code (you don't want that, and that means VS could not find/resolve to the source file, so it de-compiled your code - and even for vb.net code, it will show c#.).

So, if you fix up your references correctly, and did NOT simple copy some .dlls' of other vb.net code into the project, then you should be fine. Just reference the. dll’s in other dolls projects and let vs at build time copy the .dlls -- don't do this manually.

Comment: I am using an asp.net "Website" project, not Web application. Would it be beneficial and is it possible to create a Web "application" with the files I already have in the Website project? 

Can I follow the same steps you mentioned above if I am using a Website?

Comment: Converting to a web site application is a REALLY good idea ONLY IF YOU have just a few pages. For complex and working existing larger site, then no, it can be some work to convert to app). As for steps above? No, they change with a web site, and many reasons for this. One reason is often .dll's ARE placed in the bin folder, and also keep in mind that IIS services (the web server) will compile your web site code, not VS (this is less then ideal, and means that the vb source code files MUST be deployed to web site).  And often this means you can't clear out the bin folder.

Comment: Also means that your class code modules really need to be placed into the App_Code folder, since this is a web site. Code placed else where will not compile, and in fact if you add a simple class to the project, you see/get a NASTY warning about how you REALLY need to place that class code into App_Code, else it will not be compiled.  Not clear how you managed to add those class/code modules else where then App_Code. Needless to say, yes, one MUCH prefers a web "application" since then your build process and your code referencing process is far better. I would convert if only a few web pages

Comment: Given this is a web site, then I suggest moving all your other code modules (and class modules) into App_Code. That way at built time, they will compile. This of course does not apply to code behind for forms. However, I would double check if the project has a .sln file, since maybe this was/is a Application. The fact that modules and classes exist "outside" of App_Code suggests this was the case....